# Solve $2x''\ln (x') =x' \,\, x(0)=1, x'(0)=e$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Solve $2x''\ln (x') =x'  \,\, x(0)=1, x'(0)=e$.

My attempt

$p=x' \implies x''=pp'.$
$2pp'\ln p=p$.
$p(2p' \ln p-1)=0$.
We have that $p=0 \implies x(t)=c$ and also that $2p'\ln(p)=1 \implies \int \ln(p)dp=\frac 12 \int dx$.

$p\ln (p)-p=\frac 12x+c$.

In the picture you can See that I try to write in a different form

[image]

Comment: I hope I didn't made mistakes ..

Comment: If $p(t)=x'(t)$, then $x''(t)=p'(t)$... Note that $x''(t)$ is the derivative of $x'(t)$, that is, the derivative of $p(t)$.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum p' is according to x not t

Comment: You mean $p'=\frac{dp}{dx}$?

Comment: Because is not clear at all and you should use a more precise notation. Also... if that is the case, let's say the procedure is right: but you only got to
$$p(t) \ln p(t) - p(t) = \frac 12 x(t)+c,$$
that is
$$x'(t) \ln x'(t) - x'(t) = \frac 12 x(t)+c,$$
so you still get a differential equation.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum op take the integral according to x look carefully

Comment: I see. But what I still don't see is how this solves the problem.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum here this substitution makes thngs more complicated but with some differential equations this kind of substitution works fine ...

Comment: Ok... but there's a confusion here. When the op write $p=x'$, since $x'$ is a function $x'(t)$, they also mean by $p$ a function $p(t)$, don't they?

Comment: Or does $p$ stand for a function $p(x)$?

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum : Yes, the method is to assume that along a solution curve segment $x$ where $x$ is monotonous one re-parameterizes the curve $(t,x(t),x'(t))$ in phase space by $x$, so $t=s(x)$ and $x'=p(x)$. Then try to find a functional expression for $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have
$$2x''\ln (x') =x'  \,\, x(0)=1, x'(0)=e$$
$$2\frac {x''}{x' }\ln (x')=1$$
Substitute $\ln x' =w$
$$\implies 2w'w=1 \implies (w^2)'=1$$
Can you take it from there ?

Answer (score 1):

As I said, if $x'(t)=p(t)$, then $x''(t)=p'(t)$. So the equation can be written as
$$2p'\ln(p)=p,$$
and you can separate variables and integrate as in
$$2\int\frac{\ln(p)}p\,dp=\int dt.$$

Once you integrate use the fact that $x'(0)=p(0)=e$ and once you solve for $p(t)=x'(t)$ integrate once more to solve for $x(t)$ and use the condition $x(0)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x'$. The equation can be written as
$$
2\frac{u'}{u} \ln u=1,
$$
that is a separable equation, leading to
$$
2 \int \frac{\ln u}{u} du = t + C_1
$$
This integral can be evaluated using integration by parts identifying $U=\ln u$ and $dV = du/u$, leading to
$$
(\ln u)^2= t + C_1
$$
$$
u = \exp \sqrt{t + C_1}
$$
We have $x'(0)=u(0)=e$, then $C_1=1$. $x$ is given by
$$
x = C_2+\int u dt = C_2 + \int \exp \sqrt{t+1 } dt,
$$
This integration can be evaluated with the substitution $v=\sqrt{t+1}$, leading to $dt=2vdv$. The integral is now $2\int v \ \exp v \ dv$, which can be evaluated using integration by parts, leading to
$$
x = C_2+ 2 \left(\sqrt{t+1}-1 \right) \exp \sqrt{t+1}
$$
Using $x(0)=1$ we have $C_2=1$. Therefore, the solution is
$$
x = 1 + 2 \left(\sqrt{t+1}-1 \right) \exp \sqrt{t+1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

How did you get  $$p=x′⟹x′′=pp′$$

If you have $p=x'$ you will get $x''=p'$ why do you have an extra $p$ ?

Please fix that error and do your problem again.

The substitution is good just be careful.

Comment: Thats correct Mohammaed the derivative p' is according to x not t  so we have $p'p=x''$

Comment: @Isham Are you sure? Think about it  again.

Comment: Mohammed try it yourself $$x''=\frac {dp}{dt}=\frac {dp}{dx}\frac {dx}{dt}=p_x'p$$

Comment: The independent variable is $t$ not $x$.

Comment: He's making a change of variable so op can integrate the equation..Mohammed thats the point  And remember that t dosent appear in the equation